# Confused on snippet of code for implementing iCloud behavior on iOS

Tags: ios, swift, icloud

The code is from a book. In terms of overall app architecture (MVC), it's part of the Model. The model has two main components:

- An array of tags called `tags`
- A dictionary of tag - query called `searches`

The app saves these pieces of data in the `NSUserDefaults` (iOS defaults system) and on iCloud. The following method is called when a change in iCloud is signaled. The parameter is an instance of `NSNotification.userInfo`

```
// add, update, or delete searches based on iCloud changes
func performUpdates(userInfo: [NSObject: AnyObject?]) {

    // get changed keys NSArray; convert to [String]
    let changedKeysObject = userInfo[NSUbiquitousKeyValueStoreChangedKeysKey]
    let changedKeys = changedKeysObject as! [String]

    // get NSUbiquitousKeyValueStore for updating
    let keyValueStore = NSUbiquitousKeyValueStore.defaultStore()

    // update searches based on iCloud changes
    for key in changedKeys {
        if let query = keyValueStore.stringForKey(key) {
            saveQuery(query, forTag: key, saveToCloud: false)
        } else {
            searches.removeValueForKey(key)
            tags = tags.filter{$0 != key}
            updateUserDefaults(updateTags: true, updateSearches: true)
        }

        delegate.modelDataChanged() // update the view
    }
}
```

My question is on the if - else inside the for loop. The for loop iterates over keys that where changed; either the user adds a new search, updates an existing search, or deletes a search. But, I don't understand the logic behind the if-else. Some clarifying thoughts would be appreciated. I've read it over and over but it doesn't tick with me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if let query = keyValueStore.stringForKey(key)
```

means that *if* `keyValueStore` contains a string corresponding to `key`, then this string will be assigned to the constant `query`.

This is called "safe unwrapping":

inside the `if let ...` condition, the query is safely saved with `saveQuery` because using `if let ...` guarantees that the value of `keyValueStore.stringForKey(key)` won't be nil.

If the value is nil, then in the `else` branch, the `filter` method is used to update the `tags` array *without* the key we just processed: `tags.filter{$0 != key}` means "return all items in `tags` that are different from `key`" (the `$0` represents the current item from the array processed by `filter`).

Comment: Ah, so if the key maps to something on iCloud, then that means it exists, so save it locally (saveQuery handles both saving and updating). If the key doesn't exist anymore on iCloud, then the user probably deleted it from another device. Since it's deleted, it won't map to anything, so the query will be null. Therefore, delete that key locally and update the user defaults. That makes sense. Thanks for clarifying

Comment: Exactly. That's what I understand from this snippet of code.